# QTest::sendKeyEvent on Mac with a real (native) Ctrl modifier

Tags: qt, testing

`QTest::sendKeyEvent(...Qt::ControlModifier)` causes a Command Key sent on Mac (and vice versa all QKeyEvents on Mac having Command pressed report the Qt::ControlModifier).
What I need to do in order to achieve a real Ctrl key sending ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions exists:

- Disable the mapping transformation: [`QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_MacDontSwapCtrlAndMeta)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum)
- Use the `Qt::MetaModifier` (Control key on mac is by default mapped to `Qt::MetaModifier`)

As mentioned in the docs, this mapping is normally expected by macOS users, as shortcuts are normally using the Command key instead of the Control (which is used on other platforms).

#### References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum

Comment: great, I didn't know about Qt:AA_MacDontSwapCtrlAndMeta yet.